# Influx index and high cardinality

Tags: influxdb

I have a high throughput system. I found out that since many events has the same timestamp, influx had overwritten many events.

Therefore I tried moving from milliseconds to nanoseconds, but since I am using JAVA, I couldn't get the real clock based nanoseconds.

I came up with this solution:
I created a new tag called "descriptor" which for each event I insert a random number between 1-1000. These values are fixed and the probability for the same timestamp with the same random descriptor value is very low.  This fixes my problem and I can see all the events.

My question is wether it is OK to use these 1000 values - since this is a tag and I understand it can mess up my index and my performance?

Regards, Ido

Comment: Are there really no other unique features about the events (or their sources) you could use as a tag?

Comment: None.. I have event id uuid. But this is worse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Influxdb performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040862/influxdb-performance-issue)

Answer (score 0):

As the random "descriptors" are completely uncorrelated to other event tags, in the worst case this could increase your series cardinality by 3 orders of magnitude. This is because each existing series `(s)` will potentially split into up to 1000 unique series `(s,1),(s,2),...,(s,1000)`.

How much of a problem this is will depend on your existing series cardinality. Increasing from 10 to 10,000 is probably no big deal. Increasing from 100,000 to 100,000,000 is more likely to be an issue. You would need to experiment and profile to see.

An alternative approach might be to encode the "descriptor" in the microsecond and/or nanosecond component(s) of the timestamp (as you're not using them anyway) to make them unique.