# Influxdb performance issue

Tags: influxdb

We have a distributed system that runs on high load therefore we have experienced some data lost due to influx overriding  points that had arrived in the same time exactly. Tried to move to nano seconds precision but since we work with Java, we could not find the real nano seconds in clock way. So we did something else, I fear, that might causing us performance issues.

We added a tag called distinctor, which we random a integer value between 1-1000. This insures all points are inserted an nothing got overwritten. But Influx started working slowly after sometime. Restart fix it and it started working fast again.

Can this happen because of the extra tag? it is a low cardinality value.

We are on testing phase so we are running on AWS micro machine.

Regards,
Ido

Comment: I don't think having the `distinctor` tag is a bullet proof solution. Which `Java` version are you using? Because you can actually get high resolution time, up to nano seconds, in `Java` 9's clock implementation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html

Comment: Im using java 8.  Cant upgrade unfortunately

Comment: What sort of data are you collecting that might cause the collision? Can each system be writing to their distinct `measurement`? Or they have to go to a common `measurement`?

Comment: Each service goes to its distinct measurement but each service has multiple machines operating with multiple threads

Comment: Just brainstorming here. Is there a possibility we can `tag` the point data with the `mac address` of a particular machine? Then further categorise the point data by tagging them using the `Thread` id. That way we can avoid collision. I'm not sure what data are we storing here, just a thought.

Comment: Maybe... So you say we need to lower the cardinality. Take like 30 possible values... if there are 10 threads on 3 machines.  Thanks  for your help

Comment: Actually i'll suggest you to write all of the data to a single measurement. This is because `influx` doesn't support `joins` across measurements. Just tag your data with the appropriate tag. E.g. ThreadId, MacAddr and ServiceId. In fact it makes absoluate sense to tag your data appropriately as it gives meaning to your data. For instance you know where each point originally came from as opposed to just raw numbers and time.

Comment: So in this case we actually creating a kind of a distinctor like I created at the beginning, only we have more meaningful data such as machines and threads. But the cardinality will be the same and influx still will have to index a lot of tag values.

Comment: Make `distinctor` a field instead of tag. Tags are indexed which requires more CPU time and more memory to handle. It will not perform well in a group by clause however. Further more, AWS micro machine has no where near enough memory to run influxdb reliably at any kind of real world datasets, even for testing.